# Vector Autoregressive Estimation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to code a VAR (Vector Autoregression) in MATLAB.

I am following the chapter [here](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2015/lec3-15.pdf),

When estimating the covariance matrix, the chapter recommends at the top of page 4,

[image]

I code this in MATLAB as,

```
W = inv(X'*X);
cov_vec_beta = kron(cov,W);
```

cov_vec_beta = $\Sigma_a$

Something is off, the estimates are note correct, is the coding correct?

Comment: Does `X` contain complex values?

Comment: X =

   [ 1.0000    0.2877   -0.2127    0.4312;
    1.0000   -1.5442    0.1310    1.8786;
    1.0000   -0.1873   -0.4474    0.7653;
    1.0000   -1.2822   -1.9899   -0.5081;
    1.0000   -0.5945   -1.1325    1.0863]

Comment: Be careful `'`is the ctranpose operator and `.'`is the transpose operator. It won't change anything if you don't have complex number but still...What is the meaning of your matrix `cov` ? Have you noticed that what is called `cov` in your equation have a tilde so it should be an estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the definitions used by the [Vec Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and the identity matrix defined in the chapter:

```
vec_beta=reshape(beta,[],1); % Reshape one vector column at time
kron_AB=kron(A,B);   %Kronecker Tensor Product
I_k=eye(k);          %kxk Identity matrix
```

But yes, you should do:

```
cov_vec_beta=kron(S_alpha,inv(X'*X))
```